# Checked list box - checked items

Tags: c#, winforms

I have made this small application for employee salary calculation. I have added a checked list box where user can tick multiple checkboxes for choosing benefits. The program will check all the items checked and will add the values tick. How should i do this? So far I tried this but it doesn't work

```
    private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
        {

            foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.)
            {
                Sum = Sum + Int32.Parse(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.ToString());
            }
        }
        //textBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(Sum);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LINQ` for that:

```
 var sum = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.OfType<object>()
           .Sum(x => int.Parse(x.ToString()));
```

Or change your `for` loop to `foreach`:

```
int Sum = 0;

foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    int result;
    if(int.TryParse(item.ToString(), out result))
            Sum += result;
}
```

Comment: thanks alot :)
that helped alot

Answer (score 0):

to make it short

```
        int result = 0;
        foreach (var seleted in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
           result += int.Parse(seleted.ToString());
        }
```